# How to make paragraph visible when click on button?

Tags: javascript, html

¨
I need that when click button it appear my paragraph

```
      <button class="con-button" type="button">SUMBIT</button>
      <p id="d-c" class="d-c">Thanks for contacting <strong>Deni Beatz</strong>,your message has been sent 6 <u>Reply of Deni Beatz will be send you on mail with <strong>Contact</strong> on fastest type possible</u></p>
      <script>
        
      </script>
```

¨

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: add a hidden class to the paragraph and remove the class on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a eventListener to your button and afterwards use the toggle funktion. take aa look to the exmaple below:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.con-button');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const dc = document.querySelector('#d-c');
  dc.classList.toggle('hide')
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
      <button class="con-button" type="button">SUMBIT</button>
      <p id="d-c" class="d-c">Thanks for contacting <strong>Deni Beatz</strong>,your message has been sent 6 <u>Reply of Deni Beatz will be send you on mail with <strong>Contact</strong> on fastest type possible</u></p>
```

Comment: It works but it only hide paragraph when i clicked on it when i refresh page it show paragraph as default

Comment: @DeniBeatz To fix this problem you have to add only the css class hide to the related paragraph: ` <p id="d-c" class="d-c hide">`.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this as follows :

HTML

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="showParagraph()">SUMBITe</button>
<p id="myParagraph" style="display: none;">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

JS

```
function showParagraph() {
  document.getElementById("myParagraph").style.display = "block";
}
```

you can use getElementByClassName too. here I presented an Id for elements. if you want to hide the paragraph again you can use a condition and change "block" to "none"

Answer (score 0):

```
  <button class="con-button" type="button" onClick = "visiBiliti()"enter code here>SUMBIT</button>
    <p id="d-c" class="d-c">Thanks for contacting <strong>Deni 
       Beatz</strong>,your message has been sent 6 <u>Reply of Deni Beatz will 
      be send you on mail with <strong>Contact</strong> on fastest type p 
      possible</u>
   </p>
      <script>
        const visiBiliti = ()=>{
          document.getelementById("d-c").style.visibiliti="visible"
        }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function hideP(){
document.getElementById("d-c").style.display = "none"
}
```

```html
  <button class="con-button" onclick="hideP()" type="button">SUMBIT</button>
      <p id="d-c" class="d-c">Thanks for contacting <strong>Deni Beatz</strong>,your message has been sent 6 <u>Reply of Deni Beatz will be send you on mail with <strong>Contact</strong> on fastest type possible</u></p>
```